# Getting instance of a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, instance, sceditor

I'm using [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) and am loading it as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Create var to store emoticons
    var emoticons = false;

    $.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json')
    .done(function(response) {
        emoticons = response;
    })
    .always(function() {
        // always initialize sceditor
        $(".sceditor").sceditor({
            // Options here...
        });
    });

})
```

Now, I'm wondering how I go about getting the `instance` of this plugin so I can later pass it in if I want to reference it via a user action on the page.

For example, they have an [API](http://www.sceditor.com/api/) of which, what I would like to do is be able to get the *value* of the editor when the user clicks a preview button, it appears you can do that with [this method](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/val/).

My problem is, I'm not sure how I go about referencing the instance created?

I know how I could get it if I was running the code on the same request of when it was created, but not afterwards via a user action.

Comment: You could store it in the same way you do the emoticons.. though, you of course first have to figure out how to get the instance, which you'll need to look at the plugin's documentation and/or source to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get the instance of a specific editor:

```
var instance = $('.sceditor:first').sceditor('instance');
```

Then you get the current value, possibly filtered by plugins, like so:

```
var value = instance.val();
```

If you want the rendered HTML value, do this:

```
var value = instance.getWysiwygEditorValue(false);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery specific selectors to search in a full webpage. It is very slow. I advice instead of: `$('.sceditor:first')` use `$('.sceditor').first()`